# ASP.NET Core Globalization and Localization

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-mvc, globalization

I have found some useful articles for creating multilingual and multicultural applications in ASP.NET Core like

- [Globalization and Localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization)
- [Building simple Multilingual ASP.NET Core website](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/codefusion/archive/2016/10/13/building-simple-multilingual-asp-net-core-website.aspx).
- [Adding Localization to ASP.NET Core with user selection](https://andrewlock.net/adding-localisation-to-an-asp-net-core-application/).
- [Using Data Annotations and Localization in ASP.NET Core.](https://damienbod.com/2015/10/24/using-dataannotations-and-localization-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6/)

and a github project providing an example for implementation

- https://github.com/PankajRawat333/Globalization-and-localization-in-ASP.NET-Core

The approach I decided to follow is the third one on the above list since I wanted to give to my users the option to select the culture even though I had some issues with tha Data Annotation Localization

However I thought I should ask if anyone has any more interesting approaches and article resources to share before I started my first ASP.NET Core MVC application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have wrote some articles regarding localization in ASP.NET Core 2.1, it addresses common localization issues like localizing data annotations and client side validation:

http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/10-Developing_Multicultural_Web_Application

and provided a github project as well, additionally you can check this article as well for localizing identity error messages:

http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/20-Localizing_Identity_Error_Messages

Comment: Not working in asp.net 2.0, It creates routes like http://localhost:54794/?culture=de but still does not display correct culture name etc

Comment: I cannot see any controller in your project, i downloaded from https://github.com/LazZiya/MyTrips

Comment: @JitendraPancholi the tutorial as mentioned in the answer is for dotnet core 2.1, it has no controllers because it is based on razor pages not mvc.you may need to do some modifications in order to adopt to mvc pattern

Comment: btw, the official support period for dot net core 2.0 is already finished, it is better to switch to a newer version https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: re the culture parameter routing, you need to create and register the [Culture Route Model](http://ziyad.info/en/articles/12-Configuring_Culture_Route_Model)

Comment: Thanks for giving me clarity, and I cannot switch to 2.1 or 2.2 as both are buggy frameworks, I had faced 100% CPU consumption problem with both frameworks and I had to switch back to 2.0, many people were facing same issue, might be MS fixed this in 3.0 but not sure.

Comment: and I followed other article for 2.0 which worked well, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found some useful articles for creating multi language in asp.net mvc and angular.
The first one is going to multi language asp.net mvc and second link is going to multi language in angular

First
https://findandsolve.com/articles/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-razor-step-by-step

Second
https://findandsolve.com/articles/globalization-and-localization-using-angular-or-multi-language-select-using-angular-i18n-example-step-by-step